# How can I reference settings from the parent project in an sbt subproject?

Tags: scala, sbt

I would like to change a setting in a subproject to match the setting in the parent project. Yet I cannot find a way to reference the parent project at all.

In particular I would like to have something like:

```
publishTo := (parent / publishTo).value
```

in my subproject/build.sbt

But I haven't been able to find a way to reference the parent project.

Comment: Replace `parent` by the actual parent project name (use `show` to check from SBT prompt)

Comment: I've tried that, but I get an error that it is undefined.

Comment: What do you call a parent project?